# how to make terminal remember ssh passphrase

Tags: ssh

I have always to enter my ssh passphrase (I use ubuntu), I used ssh-add :

```
ssh-add /home/ismail/.ssh/id_rsa
```

but this makes terminal remember my passphrase till I reboot.
Is there a way to make my terminal remember my passphrase FOREVER ?

Comment: Why don't you just remove your passphrase, what's the difference?

Comment: the distant ssh server require a keyphrase to be able to login

Comment: As far as I know, SSH passphrases are a purely client-side concept, and can't be enforced by the server. Are you sure, the server isn't just asking for a password because your key isn't used?

Comment: maybe you are right, but even though, I don't want delete my key for security reason. I think ssh-agent can add the key to the keyring, any idea about that ?

Comment: @Misch is right. The passphrase is just a layer of encryption applied to a particular copy of a private key file. `ssh-keygen` can be used to change or remove the passphrase for a private key file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is possible. Probably not, because it woudn't make much sense. Making your terminal remember your passphrase forever would in some extend mean that the passphrase has to be stored on your hard drive somewhere. This is just as secure as not having a passphrase at all, so I'd suggest you just remove your passphrase. You just have to make sure that your account is secured, so that nobody can steal your private key.

Comment: this makes sense :) but I think there can be a way to save it in a file and let the terminal remember it

Comment: did you try this ? http://dtek.net/blog/how-stop-gnome-keyring-clobbering-opensshs-ssh-agent-ubuntu-1204